# Select bin/tray when printing with javax.print

Tags: java, printing

I'd like to specify the input bins when printing with Java. I've found the MediaTray class which should correspond to the input bins:

```
The following standard values are defined for input-trays (from ISO
DPA and the Printer MIB):

'top': The top input tray in the printer.
'middle': The middle input tray in the printer.
'bottom': The bottom input tray in the printer.
'envelope': The envelope input tray in the printer.
'manual': The manual feed input tray in the printer.
'large-capacity': The large capacity input tray in the printer.
'main': The main input tray
'side': The side input tray
```

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2911

The problem is, that I get a number from the application which specifies the input bin. Can I simply map the enum int values or what is the common way to get to the enum value with a number? Is it even officially supported to number the trays?

I couldn't find attributes in the RFC that correspond to the output bins. Is there also a way to do that?

And the most important question: Is the printer interface more or less reliable? Most threads I found where people asked about the trays eventually gave up, because they couldn't get it to work.

Any experiences would be appreciated.

Comment: *"And the most important question: Is the printer interface more or less reliable?"*  Maybe this API is Sun/Oracle's contribution to environmentalism.  'Save the trees!'  ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing with Attributes(Tray Control, Duplex, etc...) using javax.print library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328012/printing-with-attributestray-control-duplex-etc-using-javax-print-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These attributes are defined in [`javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaTray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaTray.html). See also, [*Standard Attributes: Media*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/attributes.fm5.html).

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I've already found MediaTray. The article which you've posted, contains lots of useful information, e.g. how to subclass MediaTray for String attributes. However, I couldn't find explicit information in it to answer one of my questions.

Comment: You mention that the application specifies the input bin by number. What application? Is that numbering scheme documented anywhere? Absent knowing, you could compare the number to the `EnumSyntax#getValue()` for a particular `MediaTray` constant.

Comment: It may be easier to examine the ` MediaTray` constants directly, e.g. `TOP` is 0, `MIDDLE` is 1, etc.

Comment: I can't tell you the name of the application. Anyway, I will just try to use the values of the constants and see if it works. As this has been the only answer to help me further, I'll accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @box: Thank you. Ping me in a comment if you add an answer or update your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the actuall tray number instead of the general constants like TOP, you'll have to do some extra coding.
There isn't any enum that lists all the tray numbers for a given printer because it isn't known at the time of coding how many trays there will be.
You need to query the **printer service** for all it's supported attribute values for the attributetype `Media.class`. This will give you a list of different types.
Print the results, the trays should be somewhere in this list. It's important to take the tray from this list and not to construct it yourself because some internall code in the printing framework is linked to this.

**Note**:
The printing api has some bugs related to tray printing (especially on unix).
To resolve them quickly, vote for:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7107175 and/or
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7107138

Answer (score 1):

This how to print to "Tray 1" (if it exists):

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
Media[] supportedMedia = (Media[]) prnJob.getPrintService().getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, null, null);
for (Media m : supportedMedia) {
    if (m.toString().equals("Tray 1")) {
        aset.add(m);
        break;
    }
}
```